# Evaluating an improper integral - issues taking the cubic root of a negative number

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem:
Evaluate the following integral.
$$ \int_{-1}^{-1} \frac{dx}{x^\frac{2}{3}} $$

Answer:

This integral includes the point $x = 0$ which results in a division by $0$. To get around this difficulty, we break the integral into two integrals.
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{-1} \frac{dx}{x^\frac{2}{3}} &= \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{dx}{x^\frac{2}{3}} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^\frac{2}{3}} \\
\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{dx}{x^\frac{2}{3}} &= \int_{-1}^{0}  x^{-\frac{2}{3}} \,\,\, dx \\
\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{dx}{x^\frac{2}{3}} &= 3x^{\frac{1}{3}} \Big|_{-1}^0
 = \lim_{x \to 0} 3x^{\frac{1}{3}} - \lim_{x \to -1} 3x^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
\lim_{x \to 0} 3x^{\frac{1}{3}} &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Am I right so far? I do not know how to evaluate the following limit:
$$ \lim_{x \to -1} 3x^{\frac{1}{3}} $$
The problem is taking the cube root of a negative number.

Comment: cube root of negative number is a real number...i.e $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -1}x^{\frac{1}{3}}=-1$

Comment: $x^n$ with $n$ odd is an odd function, thus $x^{1/n}$ is perfectly defined on negative numbers $x^{1/n}=\operatorname{sign}(x)|x|^{1/n}$. You have a typo on your upper integral bound.

Comment: @ABCD You are telling me that the cube root of $-1$ is $-1$. I agree with you.

Comment: Note that $x^{-2/3}$ is an even function, so you can use $\int_{-1}^{1}x^{-2/3}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\,dx$ and just sidestep the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cube root of a real number $p$ is the unique real number $q$ such that $q^3=p$. Therefore, $x^{\frac{1}{3}} \to -1$ as $x \to -1$ because $(-1)^3=-1$ and so $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=-1$.